# How can I limit each person to their own branch in gitlab?

Tags: git, gitlab

i have project with three branch in gitlab.
i added members to project as developers and each person has to work on a specific branch, but developer role access to another branch.
How can I limit each person to their own branch?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to [protect the given branches](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/protected_branches.html#configuring-protected-branches) and only allow certain users or keys to push to the given branch. The former is easier for the users, but only available on paid versions.

On *GitLab Free*, you have to use [deploy keys](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/protected_branches.html#allow-deploy-keys-to-push-to-a-protected-branch); those are usually meant for machines, not for humans. The users need to create a second SSH key and use that one to push to the protected branch.

On *GitLab Premium*, you can assign [users to protected branches](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/protected_branches.html#restricting-push-and-merge-access-to-certain-users).

If both variants are too inflexible for you, consider using forks instead of branches and have the developers upstream their changes via cross-project merge requests.

Comment: thanks for response,
 how to limit key? I use free gitlab, Can you explain more?

Comment: @ff.n have you looked into the linked pages yet? Note that there are more pages linked, e.g. https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/deploy_keys/index.html. The key-based approach will likely annoy your developers, so I really commend to use forks instead.